# How to get all classes containing hyphen/dash(?) applied to any DOM element and save them into array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, classname, selectors-api

How to get all classes containing hyphen/dash(?) applied to any DOM element and save them into array in JavaScript ?

My failing approach:

```js
  var getClasses     = [];
  var classesContain = [];

  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach( x => { 
  
    var y = x.className.split(' '); 
    getClasses.push(y); 
   
   });
   
  getClasses.forEach( c => { 
  
    if(c.contains('-')){ 
    
      classesContain.push(c); 
      
    } 
    
  });
```

Comment: There is no `contains()` method, but there is an [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is fairly close to working. The problem is you're pushing an *array* into `getClasses` rather than the individual classes, and neither strings nor arrays have a standard `contains` method (there's `includes`, which is probably what you mean). Also, if you only want ones containing `-`, you can filter them out earlier:

```
let classesWithDash = new Set();
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(element => { 
  for (const cls of element.className.split(' ').filter(name => name.includes("-"))) {
      classesWithDash.add(cls);
  }
});
// Now, `classesWithDash` is a set containing the class names with dashes
// If you want an array:
classesWithDash = [...classesWithDash];
```

Live Example:

```js
let classesWithDash = new Set();
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(element => { 
  for (const cls of element.className.split(' ').filter(name => name.includes("-"))) {
      classesWithDash.add(cls);
  }
});
// Now, `classesWithDash` is a set containing the class names with dashes
// If you want an array:
classesWithDash = [...classesWithDash];
console.log(classesWithDash);
```

```html
<div class="foo foo-bar"></div>
<div class="another-one"></div>
<div class="nodash"></div>
```

---

*(I have never understood why `Set` doesn't have an `addAll` method, or at least accept multiple values to `add` like `push` does...)*

Comment: `Set.prototype.add = (addImpl => function add (value, ...values) { addImpl.call(this, value); for (const value of values) addImpl.call(this, value); return this; })(Set.prototype.add);` tada! (edited to maintain backwards compatibility for zero arguments)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Yes. One can *add* it (ugh, no pun), I'm just bothered that it's not there to start with. Maybe I'll propose `addAll` though the answer is often "you can handle that in userland." (Since the spec doesn't have `add` throw on a second argument, it can't now be retrospectively updated.)

Comment: I imagine the best corollary would be to add a `concat()` method to the specification for the ES6 container classes, though I was never a fan of the `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable` semantics...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I probably should have asked you proofread the book. :-D

Comment: i get a `TypeError: element.className.split is not a function`  by this. i guess it's my fault but i dont realize why?

Comment: @RE666 if you want someone to answer you, you need to provide the context. How is `element` defined?

Comment: @RE666 - The above won't give you that error. I've added a live example.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are not realizing is that you are pushing an array of classes into your `getClasses` array. So you end up with an array of arrays, a.k.a. a 2-dimensional array.

Note, too, that you can do your extracting of classes and filtering to only those that contain dashes in one step, rather than having to process the list twice.

```js
var classesContain = [];

document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(x => {
  var y = (x.className || '').split(/\s+/g); // use a regex to cater for multiple spaces
  y.forEach(className => {
    if (className.includes('-'))
      classesContain.push(className);
  });
});

console.log('Final class list: ', classesContain);
```

```html
<div class="foo-bar bar-baz foo">
  <div class="foo-baz">
    <span class="single">Example markup</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i get a `TypeError: x.className.split is not a function`  by this. i guess it's my fault but i dont realize why?

Comment: @RE666 My bad, I completely forgot that not every element has a class! I updated my code to cater for this case. The reason was that if there is no class, `element.className` will be null or undefined. You can't call `.split()` on `undefined`. :-)

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Thanks for the code review! Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get all elements with a class that includes (`=*`) an hyphen. Convert the results to an array using `Array.from()`. Now iterate the elements with `Array.flatMap()`, get the `classlist` and convert to an array, and filter out classes that don't include a hyphen. Use a Set to make the items unique, and spread back to an array.

```js
const result = [...new Set( // use a Set to get an array of unique items
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class*="-"]')) // select all elements with classes that contain hyphens
  
  .flatMap(el => Array.from(el.classList).filter(c => c.includes('-'))) // create an array of all classes with hyphens
)]

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div class="something a-b something-else x-y"></div>
<div class="something"></div>
<div class="a-b c-d"></div>
```